# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to install Moveit with the version kinetic, when I type:
`frauas@frauas-Kinetic:~/ws_moveit$ rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic` I received the error:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:

franka_example_controllers: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libfranka]
franka_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [control_toolbox]:
franka_visualization: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libfranka]:
franka_hw: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libfranka]
franka_control: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libfranka]
moveit_tutorials: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [joy]
franka_gripper: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libfranka]

Doing `frauas@frauas-Kinetic:~/ws_moveit/src$ ls`

`franka_ros  moveit_tutorials     realtime_tools graph_msgs  moveit_visual_tools  ros_control libfranka   panda_moveit_config  rviz_visual_tools` with "libfranka" inside, I do not where it should be.

I have follow the steps of: http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#build-your-catkin-workspace

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400079/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies/) by [onkheisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/102485/onkheisen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-05-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried building the [franka_ros](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros) packages?

E.g. with these steps there: https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_linux.html#installing-from-the-ros-repositories

What errors do you see there?

Do you have these installed

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control ros-kinetic-ros-controllers 
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
```

?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-04**:
Would it have something to do with kinetic being EOL? Doesn't `rosdep update` skip EOL distributions?

EDIT in that case, they should try `rosdep update --include-eol-distros` and try again to run `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y`

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-05**:
I didn't know this flag `--include-eol-distros` for `rosdep`, thank you :) It's worth a shot for sure!

**Comment by [onkheisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/102485/onkheisen/) on 2022-05-05**:
@Joe28965 was right, I tryed with `rosdep update --include-eol-distros` and later again with my `rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic` again and it was fixed. I will study what EOL distributions are.

Thank you so much to both of you, have a nice day.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-05**:
EOL means End Of Life - http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions It's not longer actively supported. You can accept this answer and upvote comments to let others see that it's solved

**Comment by [onkheisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/102485/onkheisen/) on 2022-05-06**:
Thanks @ljaniec